# Direct proof to continuity in both variables implying continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, compactness

> Say I have a real valued function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that it is continuous in each variable. Also, assume that for any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's image under $f$ is also compact. Then $f$ is continuous.

So I've seen an argument by contradiction, but I was hoping someone could provide a direct argument. Also, can any of the assumptions be dropped or loosened? What if it is only continuous in one variable?

Can the last assumption be reduced down to "closed sets get sent to closed sets"? Why is $f$ sending compact sets to compact sets so important?

Answer (score 3):

I don’t at the moment see a direct proof, but it’s not necessary to prove the result by contradiction: one can simply prove the contrapositive. Specifically, here’s a proof that if $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is separately continuous in each variable but not continuous, then there is a compact (hence closed) subset $K$ of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $f[K]$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$.

**Proof.** By translating $f$ if necessary, we may assume that $f$ is not continuous at the origin, and that $f(0,0)=0$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$B_n=(-2^{-n},2^{-n})\times(-2^{-n},2^{-n})\,.$$

Since $f$ is not continuous at $\langle 0,0\rangle$, there is an $r>0$ such that $f[B_n]\nsubseteq(-r,r)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Let

$$\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:f[(-2^{-n},2^{-n})\times\{0\}]\subseteq(-r,r)\}\,;$$

since $f$ is continuous in the first variable, $\mathscr{B}$ is a local base at the origin.

Suppose that $B_n\in\mathscr{B}$. On the one hand, $f[B_n]\nsubseteq(-r,r)$, so there is a point $\langle x_n,v_n\rangle\in B_n$ such that $f(x_n,v_n)\notin(-r,r)$, i.e., such that $|f(x_n,v_n)|\ge r$. On the other hand, $f[(-2^{-n},2^{-n})\times\{0\}]\subseteq(-r,r)$, so $f(x_n,0)\in(-r,r)$, i.e., $|f(x_n,0)|<r$. And $f$ is continuous in the second variable, so there is a $y_n$ in the closed interval with endpoints $0$ and $v_n$ such that $r(1-2^{-n})<|f(x_n,y_n)|<r$.

By passing to a subsequence and if necessary replacing $f$ by $-f$, we may assume that we have an increasing sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Bbb N$ such that $B_{n_k}\in\mathscr{B}$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$, and $r(1-2^{-n_k})<f(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})<r$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Let

$$K=\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\cup\{\langle x_{n_k},y_{n_k}\rangle:k\in\Bbb N\}\,;$$

$K$ is closed (and indeed compact) in $\Bbb R^2$. However, $f[K]$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$, because the sequence $\langle f(x_{n_k},y_{n_k}):k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $(-r,r)$ converging to $r$, and $r\notin f[K]$. $\dashv$

---

You definitely cannot relax the requirement that $f$ be separately continuous in each variable. Let $f(x,y)=\lfloor x\rfloor$; $f$ is continuous in $y$, and if $K\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ is compact, then $K$ is bounded, and $f[K]$ is finite and hence compact. However, $f$ is clearly not even continuous in $x$, let alone continuous.

---

You may find a result of Z. Piotrowski and E. Wingler in [this paper](http://zpiotrowski.people.ysu.edu/papers/continuitypointsoffns.pdf) of interest. They show that if $f:X\times Y\to Z$ is separately continuous in each variable, $Y$ is locally connected, $Z$ is locally compact, and $f$ has a closed graph, then $f$ is continuous. In particular, any separately continuous function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ that has a closed graph is continuous.